# Change JtextField depending on JcomboBox Selected using database data - Java

Tags: java, combobox

I am having trouble getting data from data base showing how it should on a project I have.

I am after getting data from datbase then showing in the program.
When a item is selected in combo box it will show the corresponding data in a JtextField.

Here is my current code in Java

```
public Clientes() {


    initComponents();


     LigacaoBD ligaDB = new LigacaoBD();
     Connection con = ligaDB.obterLigacao();

     String query=null;
     Statement xpto;


    try {
        xpto = con.createStatement();

        query = "SELECT cod_postal, localidade FROM codigospostais";
     ResultSet rs = xpto.executeQuery(query);
     while (rs.next()){

         jtcpostal_cliente.addItem(rs.getString(1));


         jtfcodpostal_cliente.setText(rs.getString(2));
         jtfcodpostal_cliente.validate();





        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Clientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



}
```

Currently I can get the combobox working but it wont show me in the JtextField the data corresponding to the combobox.

[image: DataBase:]

Comment: jtextarea or jtextfield? a propertychangedlistener should do the trick

Comment: I mean JtextField , edited it now

Comment: How would i use propertychangedlistener  ? in this

Comment: nvm what i said about the propertychangelistener. what you need is an itemlistener on the cb

Answer (score 0):

```
    cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            String s = String.valueOf(arg0.getItem());
            tf.setText(s);
        }
    });
```

this will always change the text of you textfield to the text you selected in your combobox. i think this is what you were looking for. if not, please tell me